# Vuex actions not working properly. Shows an error "signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

Im new in Vuejs state management. I tried to make a login system with Firebase using Vuex. But getting this error.

**signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string**

Cant understand where is the problem.

```
<pre>
//  store/auth.js

export const actions = {
    loginUser(payload){
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then(user => {           
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);            
        }) 
    }
}


// Login.vue

export default {
    data(){
      return{
        email:'',
        password:''
      }
    },
    methods:{
      login(){
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/loginUser', {email:this.email, password:this.password})
      }
    }
}
</pre>
```

// Form

```
<v-flex xs12>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="email"                           
                    name="email"
                    label="Email"
                    type="email"
                    required></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>

              <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs12>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="password"                               
                    name="password"
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    required></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
```

Comment: What are the values of `this.email` and `payload.email`? Can you check they are correct?

Comment: I updated my code so you can check the form data where value of "this.email" comes

Comment: Thanks. I understood that the email value was most probably coming from a field in your component. I was more thinking of checking its value **within** the `login` method and in the `loginUser` action in the vuex store. You could simple use `console.log(this.email)` and `console.log(payload.email)`, or, better, use the vue-devtools extension (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)

Comment: when I console.log(this.email) into the login method. everything works fine. Also when I pass the right login value into the actions like this  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("email@gmail.com, "123456") that works fine.   only problem happens when I dispatch.  " this.$store.dispatch('auth/loginUser', {email:this.email, password:this.password}) "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `payload` to the action in a wrong way.

You should do:

```
loginUser(context, payload) => {
   //...
}
```

See the doc: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html